# Updating action bar navigation list item in realtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We have implemented Action bar with navigation list(custom spinner adapter) and it works as expected. But the problem comes when we want to update the selected item at runtime.

I need a way to get reference to selected item view in spinner (the one which is shown selected at action bar spinner) and then modify it as needed.

e.g. If we are showing count so selected item in navigation list is Count(10) now if i wish to change this to say Count(5) at runtime without restarting current activity. Is there a way to achieve this may be invalidate action bar etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u solved the problem?

Comment: Still experimenting with no success !!